# Set Locale in Worker

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4

I am using a worker to do some tasks in the background.

When I try to use libraries that depend on the locale (e.g. use spark.formatters.DateTimeFormatter) I notice that they fail, since the locale in the worker is not set at all (e.g. dateTimeFormatter.actualLocaleIDName is null).

**How do I set the locale in the worker?**

Things I tried that don't work:

- FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.setStyle("locale",LocaleID.DEFAULT); 
  **FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication is null**
- StyleManager.getStyleManager(null) **also returns null**, making it impossible to set the property there
- StyleManager.getStyleManager(this.moduleFactory) **null once more**

Things that work but do **not** solve the problem for me:

- Setting the locale style property manually on all DateTimeFormatter etc. instances. This would mean modifying third party library code and maintaining a fork ourselves.

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: Do you try to work with visual components in non-visual worker environment?

Comment: The libraries unfortunately do that (they don't actually have any visual components but still use e.g. the spark.formatters.DateTimeFormatter class over the flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter class).
But changing this would once again require a fork of the libraries.